# Sequence contains no elements... Thing is, I know it should

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, linq-to-entities

Background:
Using C# in the ASP.Net code-behind to call a SQL stored procedure via LINQ-to-Entities.
Also, please note that I am a complete newbie to all of this.

Problem:
I'm calling a stored procedure to get the max_length of a column in my database.
It keeps returning "Sequence Contains No Elements" when utilizing `.First()` and (alternately) the default when using `.FirstOrDefault()`.

The problem is, I know it should be returning the number "4500" as I've run the query in SQL to see what should be there.
Any ideas on why it would be doing this?
I've searched high and low, but I can't find anyone else who has had this problem where they know it should be returning a value.

Code:

```
short? `shorty = db.sp_GetMaxLength("ApplicantEssay").First();`
```

The result of the SQL query used in the stored procedure:

[image: The SQL code]

Thanks so much for any assistance you can provide!!

Edit:
The only other code involved is the ADO.Net Entity auto-generated code.
At least, it's the only other code that the program steps through when I tried to examine what was going on.
I had a hard time looking at the return and trying to figure it out, but obviously it's returning nothing):

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<short>> sp_GetMaxLength(string cOLUMN_NAME)
{
    var cOLUMN_NAMEParameter = cOLUMN_NAME != null ?
    new ObjectParameter("COLUMN_NAME", cOLUMN_NAME) :
    new ObjectParameter("COLUMN_NAME", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<short>>("sp_GetMaxLength", cOLUMN_NAMEParameter);
}
```

Edit #2: I guess I should close this question out.

I messed around with some stuff in sql, then put it back to what I had in the first place and re-executed the stored procedure. Following that, I deleted the Entity Model, reset web.config to its original state pre-model, closed Visual studio, re-opened Visual Studio, and then re-added an ADO.Net Entity Model to the project. I then re-ran the code, stepped through it, and then all of a sudden, "4500" popped up as the returned value.

I am completely flummoxed, since all the code is exactly the same without changes, but I guess that's the power of scrapping and re-starting???  No other explanation, though I hate when it's as simple as that. :-(

Thanks to all who commented. :-)

Comment: presumably your SQL code to count the items in this result set has slightly different filters from this stored procedure.

Comment: Show the code before the call to `First()` because your sequence certainly contains no elements which means something before that isn't doing what you expect it to.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks marc_s.  I'll make adjustments for that.